# Fetch count of product_id from orderdetails Table according to match order id

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to retrieve columns from below three data-tables in mysql expected output is :

- **count** (number of time the product_id exists in `orderdetails` table)
- **id** (from `products` table)
- **name** (from `products` table)

**Orders Table**

```
+-----+--------+
| id  | status |
+-----+--------+
| 124 | unpaid |
| 125 | paid   |
| 126 | paid   |
| 127 | paid   |
| 128 | unpaid |
+-----+--------+
```

**orderdetails table**

```
+-----+------------+----------+
| id  | product_id | order_id |
+-----+------------+----------+
| 332 |          1 |      125 |
| 333 |       NULL |      125 |
| 334 |        144 |      125 |
| 335 |        162 |      126 |
| 336 |        144 |      126 |
| 337 |        162 |      127 |
+-----+------------+----------+
```

**products Table**

```
+-----+------------------------------------------------------+
| id  | name                                                 |
+-----+------------------------------------------------------+
|   1 | Chaacoca Argan Oil Daily Moisture Repair Conditioner |
| 144 | Sandalwood 8oz Hand and Body Lotion                  |
| 162 | Mayumi Squalane Skin Oil - 2.17 fl oz                |
+-----+------------------------------------------------------+
```

***Expected output should look like this:***

```
+------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| product_id |count_prod|Product_name                                         |
+------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|          1 |      1   |Chaacoca Argan Oil Daily Moisture Repair Conditioner |
|        144 |      2   |Sandalwood 8oz Hand and Body Lotion                  |
|        162 |      2   |Mayumi Squalane Skin Oil - 2.17 fl oz                |
+------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Any suggested query will be helpful.

Thank you (in advance)!

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want in a tabular format.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
select p.id,od.count_prod,p.name
from products as p,
 (select product_id ,count(*) as count_prod from orderdetails group by product_id) as od
where p.id = od.product_id
```

Query Snapshot:
[image]

Comment: it's not taking output from orders table also

Comment: there is no column of the orders table in your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

you can use joins for this like :

```
select a.*,count(b.order_id) as total_order,GROUP_CONCAT(c.id) as product_ids,GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) as product_names
from Orders a 
left outer join orderdetails b on a.id = b.order_id
left outer join products c on b.product_id = c.id
group by a.id
```

Comment: actually we need group by product_id from orderdetails table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all orders have at least one detail, then you don't need the `orders` table.  You can do:

```
select od.order_id, count(*) as num_details,
       group_concat(od.product_id) as product_ids,
       group_concat(p.name) as product_names
from orderdetails od left join
     products p
     on od.product_id = p.id
group by od.order_id;
```

If products can be duplicated in `orderdetails` for a single order, then you can use `distinct` to avoid duplication:

```
select od.order_id, count(distinct od.product_id) as num_details,
       group_concat(distinct od.product_id) as product_ids,
       group_concat(distinct p.name) as product_names
from orderdetails od left join
     products p
     on od.product_id = p.id
group by od.order_id;
```

EDIT:

Based on the revised question, you want the count by products.  This is simple:

```
select p.id, p.name, count(od.product_id) as num_details
from products p join
     orderdetails od 
     on od.product_id = p.id
group by p.id, p.name;
```

If you want to include products with no order details, then use `left join` instead of `join`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying but i just attached an `expected output` please check at the bottom of the question. I am not getting the similar results.

Comment: please use `Orders` table also where `order.status' = "paid" (use all three tables for expected output `orders`, `orderdetails` and `products` tables)